# Continuous Deployment with AWS Lambda and API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-deployment, aws-lambda

Has anyone figured out a method of doing continuous deployment with AWS Lambda? We are looking at Lambda, and the new API gateway, for a very large API app we are designing for a client. It looks perfect - no servers we have to worry about, infinite scalability. But the client wants to do continuous deployment. Lambda does not have versioning, so we'd have to figure out how to increment the versions. But the idea is to do the whole thing - checkout, any code manipulation that's required, zip, send to AWS, automatically, or at worst at the push of a button.

I've had a look at Strider, and can probably use this, but there is going to be a lot of custom dev involved for scripts at each step of the build. And Strider doesn't seem to have the concept of multiple environments, so I'm not sure I can set it up to build dev, and qa, without having to have multiple bitbucket projects. We essentially have to check out the repo, create the deployment package which means moving some code around, zipping it up, and sending it to AWS.

Comment: Checkout this article one the AWS blog: http://blog.cloudbees.com/2015/07/continuous-delivery-with-cloudbees.html

Comment: Thanks. Pretty bare bones. After doing a bunch more research, and trying out API Gateway and Lamdba, we are coming to the conclusion that it is just not ready for prime time. It's missing a whole bunch of functionality that we need. Might be back to Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at this project, we are in the same boat and are about to give this a test run to handle our AWS deployments - seems like they are solving the right problems especially around environments...

https://github.com/servant-app/JAWS

Comment: That does look interesting, doesn't it? Will keep my eye on that. We are definitely back to beanstalk for this app, but next go around, maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

[LambCI](https://github.com/lambci/lambci) can do this (disclaimer: I wrote it!)

I wrote a blog post introducing it here:

https://medium.com/@hichaelmart/lambci-4c3e29d6599b#.c071nns8h

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at kappa (https://github.com/garnaat/kappa). It is a command line tool for deploying and testing AWS lambda functions.

You cannot control the API gateway settings, but at least the AWS deployment

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to start with continuous delivery is creating an auto-deployment code using s3 and aws lambda. S3 allows you do versioning and you can trigger from there a deployment to one or multiple lambda functions.

For detailed instructions to do so, read this tutorial I did:
https://cloudpointer.blogspot.com.co/2016/04/continuous-delivery-with-aws-lambda.html